# How to adjust indentation in TextMate

Tags: macos, mac, textmate, indentation

In TextMate I'd like to adjust the number of spaces added for indentation for JavaScript, CSS and PHP files. I found the bundle editor where I think this should be done, but I don't understand waht do edit.

I'm using TextMate Version 1.5.10 (1631).

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: What TextMate version?

Comment: Version 1.5.10 (1631)

Comment: You'd better indent with tabs instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not part of the language definitions. TextMate simply remembers the setting you last selected for documents of a given language setting. This setting is at the bottom of each window:

[image]

The preferences are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.macromates.textmate.plist`, in the arrays `OakTextViewScopedTabSize` (tab size) and `OakTextViewScopedSoftTabs` (whether tabs are soft). Use Xcode 4 or Property List Editor (Xcode 3) to edit this file. Or just change the setting in TextMate.

Comment: How can I change the indentation settings in TextMate? I don't find anything to adjust the number of spaces for indentation.

Comment: @BetaRide See Daniel's answer, to which I added a screenshot.